# android-maven-plugin and resource filtering

Tags: android, maven, android-maven-plugin, maven-resources-plugin

I'm newbie in maven and trying to configure it to build my android project with android-maven-plugin.
I have an application.properties file in assets directory which contains different application settings. And i want to obtain this values from my pom. In properties file i define one property as

```
myFilteredProperty=${helloFromPOM}
```

and also define the same property in POM:

```
    <properties>
        <helloFromPOM>MY PROPERTY</helloFromPOM>
    </properties>
```

Switched on filtering on assets dir

```
<build>
    ...
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>${project.basedir}/assets</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
        </resource>
    </resources>
    ...
</build>
```

And configure recources plugin as in [samples](http://github.com/jayway/maven-android-plugin-samples/archives/stable) for android-maven-plugin

```
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>initialize</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>resources</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

But when i'm trying to show Toast in my application with this property i see ${helloFromPOM} instead MY PROPERTY.

In my target directory which generated by maven i see this properties file in two places:

- /target/generated-sources/combined-assets/assets/application.properties
- /target/myapp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.apk\application.properties

First is wrong, it contains ${helloFromPOM} instead MY PROPERTY. Second, inside the apk file is correct. But when i install this apk on the device it show me wrong value ${helloFromPOM}.

What did i do wrong?

**EDIT**

Thanks for answer, I tryed it, but get this error:

> [ERROR] Error when generating sources.
>   org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException:   at
>   com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.phase01generatesources.GenerateSourcesMojo.generateR(GenerateSourcesMojo.java:338)
>     at
>   com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.phase01generatesources.GenerateSourcesMojo.execute(GenerateSourcesMojo.java:102)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
>     at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)   at
>   org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)  at
>   org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)  at
>   org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)   at
>   org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)     at
>   org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
>     at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:47)     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)     at
>   com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)
>   Caused by: com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.ExecutionException:
>   ANDROID-040-001: Could not execute: Command = cmd.exe /X /C
>   ""C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\aapt.exe"
>   package -m -J D:\projects\myapp\target\generated-sources\r -M
>   D:\projects\myapp\AndroidManifest.xml -S
>   D:\projects\myapp\target\filtered-assets --auto-add-overlay -A
>   D:\projects\myapp\assets -I "C:\Program
>   Files\Android\android-sdk\platforms\android-8\android.jar"", Result =
>   1     at
>   com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.CommandExecutor$Factory$1.executeCommand(CommandExecutor.java:215)
>     at
>   com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.phase01generatesources.GenerateSourcesMojo.generateR(GenerateSourcesMojo.java:336)
>     ... 28 more [INFO]
>   ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [INFO] BUILD FAILURE [INFO]
>   ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [INFO] Total time: 4.307s [INFO] Finished at: Wed Jun 06 10:37:14 MSK
>   2012 [INFO] Final Memory: 7M/16M [INFO]
>   ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
>   com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2:android-maven-plugin:3.2.0:generate-sources
>   (default-generate-sources) on project magent: MojoExecutionException:
>   ANDROID-040-001: Could not execute: Command = cmd.exe /X /C
>   ""C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\aapt.exe"
>   package -m -J D:\projects\myapp\target\generated-sources\r -M
>   D:\projects\myapp\AndroidManifest.xml -S
>   D:\projects\myapp\target\filtered-assets --auto-add-overlay -A
>   D:\projects\myapp\assets -I "C:\Program
>   Files\Android\android-sdk\platforms\android-8\android.jar"", Result =
>   1 -> [Help 1] [ERROR]  [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the
>   errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch. [ERROR] Re-run Maven using
>   the -X switch to enable full debug logging. [ERROR]  [ERROR] For more
>   information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the
>   following articles: [ERROR] [Help 1]
>   http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException

When i comment `<resourceDirectory>${project.build.directory}/filtered-assets</resourceDirectory>` in POM, build finishing successfull, but it doesn't use filtered assests.

Also i try to execute this `cmd.exe /X /C ""C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\aapt.exe" package -m -J D:\projects\myapp\target\generated-sources\r -M D:\projects\myapp\AndroidManifest.xml -S D:\projects\myapp\target\filtered-assets --auto-add-overlay -A D:\projects\myapp\assets -I "C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk\platforms\android-8\android.jar""` in my command line and get this error: `invalid resource directory name: D:\projects\myapp\target\filtered-assets/application.properties`. Wrong slash instead back-slash after filtered-assets. Changing `<resourceDirectory>${project.build.directory}/filtered-assets</resourceDirectory>` to `<resourceDirectory>${project.build.directory}\filtered-assets</resourceDirectory>` also doesn't help.

P.S. my plugins section looks like this

```
   <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <phase>initialize</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>resources</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
            <source>1.6</source>
            <target>1.6</target>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
        <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.0</version>
        <configuration>
            <sdk>
                <platform>8</platform>
            </sdk>
            <emulator>
                <avd>2.3.3_API-10</avd>
            </emulator>
            <undeployBeforeDeploy>true</undeployBeforeDeploy>
            <resourceDirectory>${project.build.directory}/filtered-assets</resourceDirectory>
        </configuration>
        <extensions>true</extensions>
    </plugin>
```

Comment: Thanks, I answer to your comment in question. See EDIT section

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Now it works, i change `<resourceDirectory>${project.build.directory}/filtered-assets</resourceDirectory>` to `<assetsDirectory>${project.build.directory}/filtered-assets</assetsDirectory>`. Results POM:

```
<properties>
    <myProperty>MY PROPERTY!!!!111</myProperty>
</properties>

    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>${project.basedir}/assets</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
            <targetPath>${project.build.directory}/filtered-assets</targetPath>
            <includes>
                <include>**/*.properties</include>
            </includes>
        </resource>
    </resources>

    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>initialize</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>resources</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
            <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <sdk>
                    <platform>8</platform>
                </sdk>
                <emulator>
                    <avd>2.3.3_API-10</avd>
                </emulator>
                <undeployBeforeDeploy>true</undeployBeforeDeploy>
                <assetsDirectory>${project.build.directory}/filtered-assets</assetsDirectory>
            </configuration>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
        </plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are specifying the property in your pom you shouldn't have it declared in a separate file as well. Conversely, if you want to specify it in a separate file you shouldn't declare it in your POM.

However, I am not sure exactly what you are trying to do - maven properties are only valid within your pom file and are for use during the build process. You can't access them from within your application. Android/java have no idea they exist and can't see them, so the reason you see the `${helloFromPOM}` in your code instead of `MY PROPERTY` is that android/java is just displaying the text - it doesn't know that it stands for a property and it has no way to parse it into a variable or other value.

Comment: I don't want to use POM properties from my application directly. I want to use maven resource filtering for it. http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it's caused by an inappropriate platform version.
Try to set it right in your pom file.
Look for smthg like

```
<sdk>
    <platform>17</platform>
</sdk>
```