# How to filter resources with Maven for an Android project?

Tags: android, maven, android-xml, properties-file, maven-resources-plugin

I want to use the [Maven Resources Filtering plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html) to externally define sensitive configuration data for an Android project. Therefore I created a .properties file which contains the sensitive data. It is excluded from version control.

```sh
# /.app_config.properties
# Application configuration
#
# Do not add this file to source control.
# The values are read and inserted into source files by Maven.

google.maps.v2.api.key = abc123
api.base.url = https://example.com/api
```

In the Android project I manage all sensitve data in a separate .xml file:

```
<!-- /res/values/app_config.xml -->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>    
  <string name="config_google_maps_v2_api_key">ENTER_YOUR_GOOGLE_MAPS_V2_API_KEY_HERE</string>
  <string name="config_base_url">ENTER_YOUR_SERVER_URL_HERE</string>
</resources>
```

For Maven I created another .xml file which tells which strings should be substituted when the .apk is built:

```
<!-- /filteres-res/app_config.xml -->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>    
  <string name="config_google_maps_v2_api_key">${google.maps.v2.api.key}</string>
  <string name="config_base_url">${api.base.url}</string>
</resources>
```

Here are the relevant parts of the `pom.xml` for *Maven Filtering*:

```
<!-- /pom.xml -->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
         http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <!-- Sure there is more configuration here -->

  <build>
    <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <filters>
      <filter>${project.basedir}/.app_config.properties</filter>
    </filters>
    <resources>
      <resource>
        <directory>${project.basedir}/filtered-res</directory>
        <filtering>true</filtering>
        <targetPath>${project.basedir}/res/values/</targetPath>
        <includes>
          <include>**/*.xml</include>
        </includes>
      </resource>
      <resource>
        <directory>${project.basedir}/filtered-res</directory>
        <filtering>false</filtering>
        <excludes>
          <exclude>**/*.xml</exclude>
        </excludes>
      </resource>
    </resources>
    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
          <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>${android-maven-plugin.version}</version>
          <extensions>true</extensions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>${maven-compiler-plugin.version}</version>
          <configuration>
            <compilerArgument>-Xlint:deprecation</compilerArgument>
            <!-- <resourceDirectory>${project.build.directory}/filtered-res</resourceDirectory> -->
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
        <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <sdk>
            <platform>${sdk.platform}</platform>
          </sdk>
          <undeployBeforeDeploy>true</undeployBeforeDeploy>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${maven-resources-plugin.version}</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>initialize</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>resources</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>default-resources</id>
            <phase>DISABLED</phase>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

</project>
```

The problem is the sensitive data is actually written to `/res/values/app_config.xml` instead of to the build only. This is what the file looks like after a build:

```
<!-- /res/values/app_config.xml -->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>    
  <string name="config_google_maps_v2_api_key">abc123</string>
  <string name="config_base_url">https://example.com/api</string>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 2):

The described effect is is created by the `targetPath` in your resource specification, which filters the source file and overwrites it afterwards.

The following both configurations will copy the filtered ressource in the build folder:

```
<resources>
  <resource>
    ...
    <!-- following defines a replacement target in the source part -->
    <targetPath>${project.basedir}/res/values/</targetPath>
    ...
</resource>
```

or you define it properly

```
<resources>
  <resource>
    ...
    <targetPath>${project.build.directory}/res/values/</targetPath>
    ...
</resource>
```

**But this will not create a proper apk since `com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2:android-maven-plugin` will not use the files in the build folder.**

As a conclusion we can say, there is no way using resource filter and `com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2:android-maven-plugin`. 
May be replacing the xml files in a created unsigned apk will work or your replace the xml file after the build with original.

Comment: I tried both: deleting and redefining the `targetPath` property. In both cases the app launches and **crashes** because the configuration data are **not** substituted in the compiled apk.

Comment: You are right. I tested the configuration and found that the the apk is build from the xml files in the source dir by the plugin `com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2:android-maven-plugin` plugin.

Answer (score 0):

In the Android Maven plugin you can set from where should it read the resource files, so in your pom you will have something like:

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
    <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
      <sdk>
        <platform>${sdk.platform}</platform>
      </sdk>
      <undeployBeforeDeploy>true</undeployBeforeDeploy>
      <resourceDirectory>${project.build.directory}/res</resourceDirectory>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

and:

```
 <resources>
   <resource>
     ...
     <targetPath>${project.build.directory}/res</targetPath>
     ...
 </resource>
```

Link: [android-maven-plugin and resource filtering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10900017/android-maven-plugin-and-resource-filtering)

Hope this helps.